# Adding More Than 2 Delegates in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is a simple question that can be answered fast by someone who's more familiar with Objective-C than I am- how can one add more than 2 delegates to a Class?

To clarify, I'm used to putting delegates in classes like this:

`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> { ...`

When I try to put two delegates:

`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> <UITextFieldDelegate> { ...`

...the app gives many errors, none of which help with the situation.

Is there a separator that I need to put between the delegates, or is it possible at all to have more than two?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'm not adding two app delegates, just two class delegates... See, this class is a view controller, and in the view it controls is a UIWebView and a UITextField. I want to use methods of the delegates of both those objects in my view controller class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct declaration for a class that implements multiple protocols is a comma separated list

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{ ...
```

Comment: Glad to help. Suggest that you update the wording of the question to be inline with the objective-c terminology. @protocol is analogous to the Interface keyword in othe OO languages. When reading declarations the ":" is shorthand for "subclasses" and the "<>" is shorthand for "implements".